# Type conversion string / integer

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I know that this is caused by type conversion, but can someone explain me, what exactly is happening here, when:

```
(2 == '2abd') // true
(3 == '3a') // true
```

I was a bit surprised when running into a bug by comparing a string variable against strings and integers.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If we convert `2abd` and `3a` to integers, you'll get `2` and `3` accordingly.

Since `2 == 2` and `3 == 3` both statements return `true`.

---

[Online test case](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLqyyxKD6lNLdAw0jB1lZB3SgxKUVd05pTX1@hpKg0FSFtDJY2TgRKKsBlEdIamXklmijajTAkwZpBUsbo1hrhtNEYybr//wE):

```php
<?php

var_dump(2 == '2abd');  // true
var_dump(3 == '3a');    // true

var_dump((int) '2abd'); // 2
var_dump((int) '3a');   // 3

var_dump(2 == 2);   // true
var_dump(3 == 3);   // true
```

---

For more info about operator precedence, please take a look at:

- [PHP's help page regarding this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)
- [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)
- [Rules about converting to integers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting)

Comment: So the integer conversion works via just stripping the non-integer characters from the string?

Comment: @c1u31355 Yes and this has [been fixed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison) in PHP 8.